# Show all methods name as per controller name selected in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have 2 dropdown in one of my web page build with CodeIgniter. First dropdown is Controller Name and second one is Method Name. I am able to pull all controllers and showing their names in the dropdown option. Now when user choose a controller name from first dropdown I want to show all methods name declared on that controller file in the second dropdown.

I have tried this below code..

```
foreach ($controllers as $key => $value) {

    foreach(get_class_methods($value) as $methods){
        echo $methods;
    }
}
```

here $controllers is an array of all controller name.
above code print only current class methods.i want all the methods of all the controllers.
Any idea how to do that!
so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a link which might give you list of all controllers and methods in those controllers. Hope this might help.
[Reference Link](https://github.com/pprins/CI_ListControllers)

Comment: thanks a lot...it works great..

Answer (score 0):

Create a main controller on `application/core` folder by name `My_Controller`

And the code for that is,

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Main_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();          
    }       
    public function allMethods() {
        print_r(get_class_methods($this));
    }
}
?>
```

Which ever class you have to fetch the methods should extend this controller

```
class A extends Main_Controller { }
class B extends Main_Controller { }
class C extends Main_Controller { }
```

Now the method `allMethods()` will be inherited to all controllers

To get all functions from a controller,

Suppose user selects controller `A`,

Call function like this,,
Suppose user selects controller `A`,

```
a/allmethods
```

Suppose user selects controller `B`,

```
b/allmethods
```

.... so on

So finally,

Get all methods from a controller using,

```
userselectedcontroller/allMethods
```

Hope this helps you:)